# subprocess.Popen differences btw python 2.7 and 3.*

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am porting a code from python 2.7 to python 3.* and having some unexpected issues with subprocess.Popen.

Basically I am wrapping a program in python and I call it with this command:

```
subprocess.Popen('myprogram myinputfile')
```

In python 2.7, everything works as expected. However, while *running the exact same command* in python 3.*, the program is launched but fails unexpectedly (apparently, file I/O errors). I do not have access to the source of the program.

I tried to pinpoint the differences in subprocess.Popen between python 2.7 and python 3.* but couldn't find anything relevant (bufsize for example).

Would you have clues to such a behavior ?

Thank you!

Comment: In python 3 the command line is sequence of program arguments or else a single string, ie. subprocess.Popen([cmd, file, etc] with options that may be not in python 2, check the Popen constructor in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: Can you share any details about myprogram's failures or error messages? Have you tried running the Python code + child process under strace or similar to see the exact differences in the program's behavior?